# Pad left a byte array by multiples of 8

Tags: java, android

I have a byte array that varies in length. It could be anything: a byte array from a string, bitmap data, or blob from DB.
What I want to do with this data is to pad left it so that it is of multiple of 8 bytes. So that if I have

```
byte[] hello = { 0x68, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f };
```

I want to pad it like so:

```
hello = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x68, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f };
```

And if I have

```
byte[] helloworld = { 0x68, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f, 0x77, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x6c, 0x64 };
```

I want to pad it like so:

```
helloworld = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x68, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f, 0x77, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x6c, 0x64 };
```

And so on.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is expected that questions of this type include code showing your attempt to solve the problem before asking. To better understand this site, I suggest reviewing the following: The [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), The [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and visit links on those pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core idea is to create a new array of the correct length (all values will be set to `0` by default), and then copy the content of the old array to the new array, but "skip" the first elements in the new array. We can achieve this with the following method:

```
private static final int DIVISOR = 8;

static byte[] pad(byte[] original) {
  int originalLength = original.length;
  if (originalLength % DIVISOR == 0) {
    return original;
  }
  int pad = DIVISOR - (originalLength % DIVISOR);
  byte[] result = new byte[pad + originalLength];
  System.arraycopy(original, 0, result, pad, originalLength);
  return result;
}
```

[<kbd>`ideone.com` demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/Q4si6X)

We "skip" the first elements of `result` by setting the 3rd parameter (`destPos`) of [`System::arraycopy` (`docs.oracle.com`)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,int,java.lang.Object,int,int)) to `pad`.

Answer (score 1):

> *"... What I want to do with this data is to pad left it so that it is of multiple of 8 bytes. ..."*

Utilize the *[System#arraycopy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,int,java.lang.Object,int,int))* method.

Similarly, you can derive the next multiple of *8*, by using the *[Math#ceil](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#ceil(double))* method.

Here is an example.

```java
byte[] pad(byte[] a) {
    int n = a.length, m = (int) (Math.ceil(n / 8.) * 8);
    byte[] temp = new byte[m];
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, temp, m - n, n);
    return temp;
}
```

And, here are some example usages.

```java
byte[] hello = { 0x68, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f };
hello = pad(hello);
out.println(Arrays.toString(hello));

byte[] helloworld = { 0x68, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f, 0x77, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x6c, 0x64 };
helloworld = pad(helloworld);
out.println(Arrays.toString(helloworld));
```

Output

```
[0, 0, 0, 104, 101, 108, 108, 111]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 104, 101, 108, 108, 111, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100]
```